# Google Apps Engine Backend - Javax.persistence missing - Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to migrate to Android studio and my app engine code uses the Entity framework listed below

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class AppVersion {

@Id
private String applicationName;
private int minVersionRequired;

public String getApplicationName() {
    return applicationName;
}
public int getMinVersionRequired() {
    return minVersionRequired;
}
public void setApplicationName(String applicationName) {
    this.applicationName = applicationName;
}
public void setminVersionRequired(int minVersionRequired) {
    this.minVersionRequired = minVersionRequired;
}
}
```

Just creating a backend in Android Studio (0.5.6) doesn't work, I can't import javax.persistence.*

From this [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview) I discovered that I needed to create a persistence.xml file (this was automatically created in Eclipse).  I just can't figure out where in the file structure it is supposed to go.  I understand it needs to be in the META-INF folder but I don't know where that corresponds for gradle (or if it has to be created in the gradle build file).
Current file structure:

```
-src
  -main
    -java
      -com.package.test
        class files
    -webapp
      -css
      -js
      -WEB-INF
```

Gradle build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

dependencies {
  appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.1'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.1'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.1'
  compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}

appengine {
  downloadSdk = true
  appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
  }
  endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio's App Engine samples don't use JPA.

However if you want to use JPA, you need to add the JPA dependencies, this describes where you might find out what those are https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2

So these (or some subset of these)

- asm-4.0.jar
- datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar
- datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar
- jdo-api-3.0.1.jar
- datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3.jar
- datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar
- geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar
- jta-1.1.jar

Look on maven.org for those dependencies will reveal how to include them in build.gradle files as compile dependencies:

asm-4.0 :

```
compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm:4.0'
```

datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3 :

```
compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jpa:3.1.3'
```

and so on.

You want the versions to be exactly as they are in the appengine sdk to ensure compatibility. Also make sure you run the enhance task on your project.

Comment: Well that removed the errors, I'll give you an upvote now but I'll have to test it later before I accept it.  I couldn't find the appengine-jsr107cache:1.1 or the jta:1.1 on Maven.org though.  Also, what does the enhance task do?

Comment: You need to run enhance on JPA/JDO entity classes for them to be useful by the system (http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_1/enhancer.html).  You need to run it after compile but before WAR,

so maybe something like 
    war.dependsOn appengineEnhance
might work for you.

Comment: I'm not sure sure about the jsr and jta dependencies, I wonder if those are exposed differently.  The old maven example didn't use jta so maybe you don't need to include that, but the jsr cache dependency is here : http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|net.sf.jsr107cache|jsr107cache|1.1|jar

Comment: Maybe you should try https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/ which is a persistence framework specifically for google app engine. then you dont have to run any additional tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following to the build.gradle

```
compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'
```